# Uniform convergence of series of function with two variables?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, uniform-convergence

Consider a function $f(x,y): A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and the series of function

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} f_n(x,y)\tag{1}$$

How is **unform convergence** defined for $(1)$?

Is it defined a uniform convergence "with respect to x", as y was just a parameter, as follows?

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg[\sup_{x \in A}\Bigg|\sum_{n \geq 0} f_n(x,y) - \sum_{n = 0}^{N} f_n(x,y)\Bigg| \bigg]=0$$
And analogous for $y$?

If it is, then are the theorems of switching series and integrals (not double integrals but just inegrals in $dx$ or $dy$), series and derivatives (with respect to $x$ or $y$) and series and limits (on $x$ or $y$) still valid if the convergence of $(1)$ is **uniform** with respect to the interseted variable?